# How to restore the project file C++ Builder 10.3

Tags: c++builder

Is there an easy way to restore *.cbproj file out of *.cpp, *.h, *.dfm in C++Builder 10.3 if the project file was lost or corrupted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no such option. You need to create a whole new project from scratch and add your existing source files to it as needed.